# Last review is coming up wrong

Tags: css

hi guys in following site last review http://premiumvoices.nl/all-reviews "Tim" is coming up wrong. All other reviews are coming fine
here is my code

```
.view-all-reviews .views-row {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.view-all-reviews .views-field-php {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
.view-all-reviews .views-field-title {
    font-family: "BreeSerif", "latobold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
    color: #407b92;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 24px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i believe it is because you have it as a `span`, which is an inline element, and it just happens to be too short to separate itself as a newline like the others.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea by making that span inline-block or block will help?

Comment: only if you set it to a fixed width. `inline-block` will keep the same `auto` width unless you explicitly set it, and if it stays the same width it'll have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding a `margin-right: 5px` to the field content class that the name is contained in.

The reason is that the name is too small, and where the other names are big enough that it's pushing it over to the left side, which is where you want it. Adding a margin insures that the size is big enough to push the name to the correct location. It won't change the layout of the other ones that are correct either.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of "Tim" word, which is too small. Then, `Tim *****` is smaller than your total score's div.

Clean fix:

```
.view-all-reviews .views-field-php-1 {
    clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because all three (*the name, the stars and the green section*) can fit in one line, when the name is that small.

You should `float:left` the name, and `clear:left` the green section

```
.view-all-reviews .views-field-title{
  /*
   whatever properties you set
   and then add
  */
  float:left;
}
.view-all-reviews .views-field-php-1{
  /*
   whatever properties you set
   and then add
  */
  clear:left;
}
```